# Getting WooCommerce products in one shot is slower than getting one by one

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, performance, woocommerce

I'm querying WooCommerce to get a list of 25 products, giving an array of SKUs. Then I loop through the resulting products to compare them with some data I have from an API source.

```
wc_get_products( array( 'posts_per_page'  => -1, '_sku' => $arr_skus ) );
```

this call to wc_get_products() is taking **~840** ms on a WC installation with about 22.000 products. After that, the loop with my logic is taking **~18 ms** for each interation.

I tried to replace wc_get_products() with a standard WP_Query that directly asks WordPress for products with the _sku meta data:

```
            $args = array(
                'post_type'      => 'product',
                'post_status'    => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'meta_query'     => array(
                    array(
                        'key'     => '_sku',
                        'value'   => $arr_skus,
                        'compare' => 'IN',
                    ),
                ),
            );
            $arr_existing_products = new WP_Query($args);
            $arr_existing_products = $arr_existing_products->posts;
```

Now I have my generic posts, but I prefer to operate with instances of WC_Product to take advantage of official WooCommerce properties, so I added `wc_get_product($post_id)` in my processing loop.

The generic WP_Query is taking only **~45 ms** (about 1/20 of wc_get_products()!!!), then each loop interation takes **~25 ms**

So, I'm loosing about 7 ms for each loop interation (for a total of 175 ms for the 25 products), but I'm saving 795 ms, with a resulting improvement of 620 ms.

I'm asking to myself: how can it be faster to query each post with a single wc_get_product() instead of making a single call to wc_get_products() ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You should make a custom optimized SQL query using WPDB Class to get the data that you want and make the comparison inside the SQL query. Can you tell more, updating your question, about the comparison with the data you have from an API source? May be you could add some more code related too.

Comment: They are different type of queries with different purpose. At the end all of them are wpdb queries so in that logic use only wpdb queries since they will be the fastest but you will spent more time tuning it.

Comment: Can you not do `'post__in' => [1,2,3,4]` to get them directly?
drawback: that does require that you know what products you will need.

Comment: Show us the generated SQL.  We can tell you have ot improve that.  Then, of course, you will need to figure out how to transliterate back to Woo.  Or issue the improved SQL as "raw".